# error FS1133: No constructors are available for the type 'List<'a>'

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-scripting

I created a type Person as follows which runs fine.

```
type Person = 
    { First: string; Last : string }
    override this.ToString() = sprintf "%s, %s" this.First this.Last
```

But when I try to make a list of Person as follows.

```
let people = 
    new List<_>( 
        [|
            {First = "Bhushan"; Last = "Shinde"} 
            { First = "Abhi"; Last = "Jad"}
        |])
```

It gives the error: *No constructors are available for the type 'List<'a>'*

Can someone please explain what is the problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In F#, the name `List<_>` is used to refer to the immutable F# list (defined in F# core library).

If you want to create mutable .NET list (`System.Collections.Generic.List<_>`), you need to use an alias that is defined in the F# library `ResizeArray<_>` (or you need to use fully qualified name):

```
let people =  
    new ResizeArray<_>(  
        [| 
            {First = "Bhushan"; Last = "Shinde"}  
            { First = "Abhi"; Last = "Jad"} 
        |])
```

If you want to create a normal F# list (and use it in a functional style), then you can just use the list comprehension syntax without passing the value to any constructor:

```
let people =  
        [ {First = "Bhushan"; Last = "Shinde"}  
          { First = "Abhi"; Last = "Jad"} ]
```